# Connection issue after installing NordVPN on Lubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, lubuntu, network-manager, openvpn

I'm using Lubuntu LXQt desktop version 20.04, and everything was ok until installing NordVPN. during the using NordVPN, I have no issue with the connection. but when the laptop is idle for some time and when I back to browser it seems there is no connection. so I test it with:

```
ping 4.2.2.4
```

And I get this error:

> ping sendmsg operation not permitted

Even I use `sudo` or do `login/logout`, just restarting entire the system could help me to back to the working network. obviously there is another issue. so:

**What is the problem and how I can fix it?**

NordVPN outputs:

```
$ nordvpn status
    Status: Disconnected
$ nordvpn settings
    Technology: OpenVPN
    Protocol: UDP
    Kill Switch: disabled
    CyberSec: disabled
    Obfuscate: disabled
    Notify: enabled
    Auto-connect: disabled
    DNS: disabled
```

Comment: Is ufw enabled? If it is disable it and see if it works: `sudo ufw disable`

Comment: @user68186, I'm using the `nordvpn` command-line utility.

Comment: @ldias, what is the `ufw` and why I should disable it?

Comment: `ufw` stands for uncomplicated firewall and is essentially a frontend for iptables. It is installed by default on Ubuntu. A firewall can sometimes block a VPN connection so disabling it might work. Run: `sudo ufw disable` and try again and see if anything changes

Comment: Dear @user68186, I don't know why the senior users of AskUbuntu ask the PO to edit. you are senior to me. please edit my post just like you want it. definitely, I have problems in this community. thanks.

Comment: Dear @ldias, I do it now. and I should wait to see, is it worked or not. also, I implemented what [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/562581/251423) said. maybe this setting will settle the issue.

Comment: @ldias I use `nordvpn` with `ufw` without any problems and without any rules specific for the VPN, but it is always good to check if disabling `ufw` solves the problem.

Comment: Dear @user68186, I have no output from nordvpn, after installing it I faced this issue. the main problem is this: connection lost

Comment: Can you access the Internet from browser with nordvpn disabled? What happens if you enable nordvpn using the command `nordvpn connect` command? What happens if you disable nordvpn manually by using `nordvpn disconnect` command after connecting to nordvpn first? It looks like nordvpn gets improperly disconnected and using the `connect` then `disconnect` then `conncect` again may fix it.

Comment: OpenVPN has problems reconnecting after a system suspend. When you say your laptop is idle, is it possible that it went into suspend or hibernation?

Comment: @Sebastian, it just gonna show screen saver, neither both of your said situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the Linux firewall block the NordVPN firewall and the NordVPN killswitch stop the connection, so I should stop the Linux firewall and re-run the NordVPN service and the connection will get back on track.

By using the following command:

```
sudo ufw enable && sudo ufw disable && sudo /usr/bin/systemctl restart nordvpnd
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I think I have solved this for me..
the issue was that with 20.04 the editing of etc/resolv.conf with the nordvpn alternate DNS does not work, it reverts to defaults.
so following these instructions here

https://www.ricmedia.com/set-custom-dns-servers-on-ubuntu-18-or-20/#Set_DNS_servers_with_Netplan_Network_Manager_and_static_IP

I edit my
the file to edit is etc/netplan/*.yml in my case only one file there as 01-network-manager-all.yaml .bak

now I have it set up as per above/below, and for some strange reason ubuntu is now helpfully putting my ethernet wired in as eth0 (I will try it on the other adapter later today). Ubuntu is however showing unmanaged in top right desktop  wired status, but that is not affecting anything.

> # Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system network:
>
> ```
>  version: 2
>
>  renderer: NetworkManager
>
>  ethernets:
>
>     eth0:
>
>        dhcp4: false
>
>        addresses: [192.168.1.114/24]
>
>        gateway4: 192.168.1.1
>
>        nameservers:
> ```

save file  and then

```
sudo netplan --debug apply
```

and it all now works, those alt dns addresses are from

https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/Troubleshooting/1088041672/Change-your-DNS-servers-on-Windows.htm

I disconnect the ethernet adapter from usb hub, and reconnect it, I get the nordvpn notification popup that it has reconnected, it survives the dns leak test at http://dnsleak.net - which is why I was setting alt dns in the first place.

Comment: also you can connect to any countriers server, eg US with

nordvpn connect US

Answer (score 0):

ok, with excellent support from nordvpn, there is a new client. I can now disconnect from vpn

```
nordvpn disconnect
```

, change the usb hub (ie disconnect from ethernet,), reconnect a different hub, then reconnect via terminal nordvpn. it works.

sudo apt --purge autoremove nordvpn*

```
cd ~/Downloads sudo wget 
"https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian/pool/main/nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb"
 sudo dpkg -i nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb
 sudo apt update
 sudo apt upgrade
 sudo apt install nordvpn
```

my nordvpn command is

```
nordvpn connect usxxxx && nordvpn set killswitch on &&  nordvpn status && nordvpn settings
```

where usxxx is your nominated server, you can get the best one from
[https://nordvpn.com/servers/tools/][1]

Comment: I have been back to losing the internet connectin when disconnecting and reconnecting usb hubs.... and have had to reboot.... today I have discovered that running 'service network-manager start' (either as sudo or putting in password on authorisation popup)  before disconnecting the usb hub (with the ethernet adapter on it) allows me to then reconnect the hub (or another) and the connection picks up. Nordvpn , set to autoconnect then picks up too. better than rebooting all the time.

Answer (score 0):

This can happens sometimes if you disconnect from `nordvpn` but have not turn the killswitch off. To see if this is your problem:

```bsh
nordvpn set killswitch off
```